# Coin changes to 3-leaf clover after playing sometime

Tags: temple-run-2

In Temple Run 2, I have completed Level 8. I have unlocked Scarlet and Barry bones. After playing a while the coins turned from diamond shape to 3-leaf clover. How do I bring back the coins?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Happy St. Patrick's day. I suspect they'll turn back into coins a few days from now.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the coins are back to coins now that it is past St. Patricks's Day (March 17.)

There have also been some other times when the colors of coins changed temporarily, connected to holiday events.  For example, there were pink and red hearts for coins near Valentines' Day, for example.